# Is there possible let variable which have html markup have appendTo function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, variables, append, markup

first I have two variable:

```
        var $prev="<div>This is Hello World</div>"
        var $next="<h1>This is another Hello</h1>"
```

I want the $next's markup append to $prev's,just like

```
<div>This is Hello World<h1>This is another Hello</h1></div>
```

but I know the

```
$test.append($test1);
```

is impossible,but really?How can I have the same function?

I want html manipulate function could also be apply into variable that store html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this :

```
var $prev=$("<div>This is Hello World</div>");
var $next=$("<h1>This is another Hello</h1>");
```

this creates jQuery objects - then you can use the [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method.

```
$next.appendTo($prev);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
 var $prev=$('<div>', { text: "This is Hello World"});
    var $next=$("<h1>", { text: "This is another Hello"});
```

and then you can do

```
 $next.appendTo($prev);
```

and then `$prev` is

```
<div>
This is Hello World
<h1>This is another Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var $prev="<div id='first'>This is Hello World</div>"
    var $next="<h1>This is another Hello</h1>"
```

insert `$rev` to page

```
$('some_element').append($prev);
```

and then

```
$('#first').append($next);
```